# The apache2 configtest failed. Segmentation fault (core dumped) Action 'configtest' failed

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, php-7

The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
------------------------------------------------
Error logs:-

 [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30111] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
 [core:notice] [pid 30111] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
 [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30111] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem may occur if you have installed php5.6 and php7. Run:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: ok, but it not explain how to solve the problem, juste a cure you have to do each time you update your package.

Comment: umm... that means if i have php 5.6 installed and have upgraded to php 7.2 i would need to do `sudo a2dismod php5.6` if i want to continue with php 7.2

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have multiple versions of php installed on your
system(mostly php version 5 and php version 7+).

All you need to do is disable version of php7 and enable php version 5.

Follow these commands-

> sudo a2dismod php7.0 (or php 7.2 -if php 7.2 version is installed )
>
> sudo a2enmod php5.6
>
> sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6

and then restart apache server by this command-

> systemctl restart apache2